# What is the default browser, find out programmatically on Android

Tags: android, android-browser

I want to find out, programmatically, the package name of the default browser.

(And knowing the package name, I can, for example, place its icon on a button, or launch without a launcher.)

There is `resolveActivity()` in `PackageManager`, but the Google docs say: *If multiple matching activities are found and there is no default set, returns a ResolveInfo containing something else, such as the activity resolver.*

Answer (score 3):

I hope someone can write something more elegant. But this stuff works:

```
public static ComponentName getDefaultBrowserComponent(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent()
        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .setData(new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme("http")
                .authority("x.y.z")
                .appendQueryParameter("q", "x")
                .build()
                );
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ResolveInfo default_ri = pm.resolveActivity(i, 0); // may be a chooser
    ResolveInfo browser_ri = null;
    List<ResolveInfo> rList = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : rList) {
        if (ri.activityInfo.packageName.equals(default_ri.activityInfo.packageName)
         && ri.activityInfo.name.equals(default_ri.activityInfo.name)
        ) {
            return ri2cn(default_ri);
        } else if ("com.android.browser".equals(ri.activityInfo.packageName)) {
            browser_ri = ri;
        }
    }
    if (browser_ri != null) {
        return ri2cn(browser_ri);
    } else if (rList.size() > 0) {
        return ri2cn(rList.get(0));
    } else if (default_ri == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return ri2cn(default_ri);
    }
}
private static ComponentName ri2cn(ResolveInfo ri) {
    return new ComponentName(ri.activityInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name);
}
```